# The most weird thing I ever met: the ESI register got an invalid value right after the assignment

Tags: debugging, assembly, crash-dumps, cpu-registers

We have a server process running on windows 7 wrote in C++ with multiple threads. And we got a random crash just at a simple assignment, please see the following instructions:

```
--- some function without the source:
0136E0F0  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+8]
0136E0F4  mov         edx,dword ptr [esp+0Ch] 
0136E0F8  push        esi  
0136E0F9  mov         esi,dword ptr [ecx+10h]          << read a member variable to esi
0136E0FC  add         dword ptr [ecx+esi*8+30h],eax    << access violation here!
...
...
```

The weird thing is, when the crash happening, the value of [ecx+10h] is 0 but the ESI is a non-zero invalid value! And then the last instruction tries to write to an invalid memory! (We checked them from the crash dump file). **which means, the object at ecx is valid but the register is corrupted!!!** Maybe I am wrong but the OS will preserve all the registers when switching threads, right?

So my question is, what really happened here and how to fix it?

Many thanks.

Comment: does the crash happen every time or only during certain conditions, ie: if you step through this code in a debugger, does it show that ESI is being corrupted?. you are correct about register preservation on context switch by the OS however, assuming you are running in userland without any dodgy changes to the OS that may cause instability.

Comment: thanks for your attention. the crash happened randomly and we do not known which condition to reproduce it, that's the big problem now. (another one is we don't have the source code). this piece of code should be right since its a general function frequently used at other places. we can see the esi is corrupted in the debugger by launching the crash dump file(but the [ecx+10h] is 0 just before the crash).

Answer (score 1):

What other piece of code is messing with the data at ecx+10h?

There is plenty of scope between the mov from memory to esi, and the later usage of esi, for the memory to have changed. It then appears as if esi should have a good value.

Just imagine a different thread or interrupt stepping in to put something valid at ecx+10h, after a 0(?) was read from that location.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty common cause for these "impossible" errors: Faulty hardware. The CPU might me failing or too hot.

This happens more often than people think. Hardware is not either working or not-working. It can be mostly working except for one case in 1e10 opportunities.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but actually this happened many times. sometimes it came out if too many exceptions occurred and sometimes when too many connections. we have installed this server on many machines and all of them have this crash. because its a part of a critical server so we really get headache about it.